# iphone app with in app purchases and non app store

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have a question regarding the apple licence over in-app purchases

I have the following scenario: I have a site that is a store of avatars (just like a mii or a xbox live avatar) where my users can buy items, just like hats or tshirts … all kinds of virtual goods for an avatar.

I want to make a game for iphone were you can load this avatar.

In this app, you login using you user account (I mean the user I have registered in my site), then your avatar is loaded and thats all.

As far as I know, I am not allowed to buy things if they are not bought using the apple in-app purchase system.

but certainly my users will be buying lots and lots of other things for their avatars in my site.

So the question is, will my app be allowed to be in the apple store?

I have read enough and I think that if I doesn't mention anywhere in the iphone app, that an external store exist, my app will be allowed or not?

Comment: i think to solve this..you should look into Facebook app and check if they allow pay to promote post within the app..i.e the payment is done within the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they can buy content outside of the application that will be used inside of the application, that's usually fine so long as the application doesn't provide a link for them to buy from outside of the App Store.  If somebody can tap a button in your application and be taken to your website where you can buy things for use in the application, Apple will probably reject it.